# Bind rpz only gives max TTL of 5 seconds

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

When I configure BIND with response policy zone so I can override DNS for LAN network I have noticed that TTL returned by this DNS servers max out at 5 seconds. I can lower TTL to 1-4 seconds but setting anything higher than 5 will just stay at 5 seconds. (I tried setting both $TTL 3600 & inline eg. testdns.domanin.net 3600 IN A x.x.x.x)

I have noticed this originally on my pfsense box configured with BIND but then I setup another test server under Ubuntu and exactly same happens also over there.

My configuration is based on https://deteque.com/m3aawg-bind-training/ which is mentioned in this document https://www.isc.org/docs/BIND_RPZ.pdf

I spend significant time testing different setting and although DNS returns correct records TTL times are wrong as stated above and for my purpose 5 seconds is really not usable.

Only configuration which in my knowledge is able to limit TTL is `max-zone-ttl` but that is only applicable in combination with DNSSEC (https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9.18.13/reference.html#namedconf-statement-max-zone-ttl)

This affects in my case both version 9.16 & 9.18.

Is there something I missing or is this some sort of undocumented RPZ limitation?

Thank You to anyone who can shed some light into this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the `max-policy-ttl` in the `response-policy` statement (the default 5 seconds is coming from there):

> max-policy-ttl: May appear inside an specific zone definition (in the
> zone section) of a response-policy statement in which case it affects
> only that zone, or outside (in the global section) where it affects
> all zones (unless overridden by the same parameter inside any specific
> zone definition). The outcome of policy processing changes the
> response in the resolvers cache. By default, irrespective, of the
> original response TTL, the modified response TTL is set to 5 seconds.
> Thus, if you want to force the responses to live in the cache for a
> long period then define a (much) longer ttl value with a parameter
> like, say, max-policy-ttl 172800 (2 days defined in seconds).
> Consider, however, that any updated RPZ zone files (master or slave)
> may modify the behavior of any policy trigger or action including
> removing it entirely. Modifying the default TTL value to an long time
> period - a superficially attractive strategy - may have the unintended
> consequence of marooning unnecessary records in the cache.

From https://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/rpz.html#response-policy
(License [CC BY-NC](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/))